# how to print a char array using a pointer only? (we don't know the size of the array)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a function with three parameters: a pointer to a character array (also known as a C-String), and two pointers to specific characters (we will assume that they point to characters in the C-String).

```
void stringPointerOperation(char* str, char* firstPtr, char* secondPtr)
{

 cout << str << endl;
 cout << "First character=" << *firstPtr << endl;
 cout << "Second character =" << *secondPtr << endl;

 }
```

Questions:

1. How do I print out the characters from firstPtr to the end of str?
2. How do I find out how many characters are between firstPtr and secondPtr?

Comment: Keep printing characters until you get to `\0`. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: no, that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1:

If your array of `char`s is properly formatted, it should be null-terminated (i.e., the last character should be `\0`). Simply print characters until you get there, as:

```
while(*firstPtr != '\0') {
    cout << *firstPtr << endl;
    *firstPtr++;
}
```

Answer to question 2:

If you are sure they are pointers to the same array of characters, simply subtracting them should work:

```
int charsBetween = secondPtr - firstPtr;
```

Comment: I presume you mean `cout << *firstPtr << endl;`

Comment: @deau I think it should *really* be `cout << *firstPtr++;`, without the auto-increment you get an infinite loop.

Comment: The first one could just be replaced with `cout << firstPtr << endl;`. No need to rewrite that loop.

Comment: Whoopsie; was correcting the OP and made the exact error I was correcting!